# What's the difference between a hash with => and :

Tags: ruby

I use a specific library where I can pass variables with such an hash:

`{ 'username' = > 'John'}`

But when I try to pass the variables with such an hash:

`{ 'username': 'John' }`

It doesn't work. I always thought `=>` is the old syntax for `:` but there seems to be really a difference.

Code where it's used: `Liquid::Template.parse(template).render!(variables).html_safe`

**Can you please explain the difference and tell me how I can convert such an hash: `{ 'username': 'John' }` to this `{ 'username' = > 'John'}` presentation?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```ruby
{ some_arbitrary_expression(some_argument, arg2) => another_arbitrary_expression(arg) }
```

Is the *general* syntax for `Hash` literals. *Any* object that responds to `hash` and `eql?` can be used as a key in a `Hash`.

```ruby
{ some_valid_symbol: arbitrary_expression(arg1, arg2) }
```

Is the "new-style" `Hash` literal syntax for `Symbol` keys.

> I always thought `=>` is the old syntax for `:` but there seems to be really a difference.

I'm not sure where you were taught this, but I sure would like to know so I can warn others about this source. It has never been true, there are no current plans to make it true, and it probably never will be true. To my knowledge, there is nothing in the official documentation, in the RubySpec, or in any of the well-known books (The Ruby Programming Language, Programming Ruby) that says it either.

> Can you please explain the difference and tell me how I can convert such an hash: `{ 'username': 'John' }` to this `{ 'username' = > 'John'}` presentation?

You can change the `String` representation of a `Hash` by monkey-patching `Hash#to_s` or `Hash#inspect`, but it is unclear what that would buy you.

If a method you are using expects a `Hash` whose keys are `String`s and you pass it a `Hash` whose keys are `Symbol`s, then changing the `String` representation of the `Hash` is not going to help you. You need to fix the source and make sure that your keys are `String`s.